# Unable to create spring bean ElasticSearchTemplate

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am getting an error when launching my `SpringBoot` application. Below is the stacktrace -

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate]: Factory method 'elasticsearchTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.doSearch(Lorg/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder;Lorg/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/SearchQuery;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchResponse; @306: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AbstractAggregationBuilder' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AggregationBuilder'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @306
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate', 'org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder', 'org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/SearchQuery', 'java/util/Iterator', 'org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AbstractAggregationBuilder' }
    stack: { 'org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder', 'org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AbstractAggregationBuilder' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2cb9 0076 0100 c600 0e2b 2cb9 0076 0100
    0x0000010: b600 7757 2cb9 015f 0100 b800 a19a 002d
    0x0000020: 2cb9 015f 0100 b900 dc01 004e 2db9 00b9
    0x0000030: 0100 9900 182d b900 ba01 00c0 0160 3a04
    0x0000040: 2b19 04b6 0161 57a7 ffe5 2cb9 0162 0100
    0x0000050: b900 b301 009a 0035 2cb9 0162 0100 b900
    0x0000060: dc01 004e 2db9 00b9 0100 9900 202d b900
    0x0000070: ba01 00c0 0163 3a04 2b19 04b6 0164 1904
    0x0000080: b601 65b6 0166 57a7 ffdd 2cb9 0167 0100
    0x0000090: c600 352c b901 6701 004e 2dbe 3604 0336
    0x00000a0: 0515 0515 04a2 0020 2d15 0532 3a06 2bbb
    0x00000b0: 0168 59b7 0169 1906 b601 6ab6 016b 5784
    0x00000c0: 0501 a7ff df2c b901 6c01 00b8 00a1 9a00
    0x00000d0: 352c b901 6c01 00b9 00dc 0100 4e2d b900
    0x00000e0: b901 0099 0020 2db9 00ba 0100 c001 6d3a
    0x00000f0: 042b 1904 b601 6e19 04b6 016f b601 7057
    0x0000100: a7ff dd2c b901 7101 00b8 00a1 9a00 2d2c
    0x0000110: b901 7101 00b9 00dc 0100 4e2d b900 b901
    0x0000120: 0099 0018 2db9 00ba 0100 c001 723a 042b
    0x0000130: 1904 b601 7357 a7ff e52c b901 7401 00b8
    0x0000140: 00a1 9a00 322c b901 7401 00b9 00dc 0100
    0x0000150: 4e2d b900 b901 0099 001d 2db9 00ba 0100
    0x0000160: c001 753a 042b 1904 b901 7601 00b6 0173
    0x0000170: 57a7 ffe0 2a2b 2cb9 0074 0100 b600 75b6
    0x0000180: 0078 b700 79b0                         
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@20)
    append_frame(@44,Object[#709])
    chop_frame(@74,1)
    append_frame(@100,Object[#709])
    chop_frame(@138,1)
    append_frame(@161,Object[#828],Integer,Integer)
    chop_frame(@197,3)
    append_frame(@221,Object[#709])
    chop_frame(@259,1)
    append_frame(@283,Object[#709])
    chop_frame(@313,1)
    append_frame(@337,Object[#709])
    chop_frame(@372,1)
```

I am wondering if this is related to any maven dependency conflicts. Could anybody explain what below reason means? Any help would be great.

> Type
>   'org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AbstractAggregationBuilder'
>   (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to
>   'org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/AggregationBuilder'

Comment: which version of spring boot and es you are using?